# Artifacts / Lines in triplanar mapping

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, godot

I've tried a couple of triplanar shaders in [godot](https://godotshaders.com/shader/hextiling-triplanar-terrain/) as well as the official [visual shader node](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_visualshadernodetextureparametertriplanar.html) but they all seem to produce lines/artificacts:
[image: lines in the texture]

Is this inherent in triplanar mapping or more likely a bug elsewhere?

If it's inherent, do other techniques exist without this inherent issue that can add meshes to procedurally generated geometry?